# Lombok @SuperBuilder example with json annotations

Tags: java, lombok

can someone please provide me a working example with the lombok @SuperBuilder experimental annotation?

I can't get it running and there is no code example as documentation available.

Currently my code looks like this:

Superclass:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubA.class),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AnotherSub.class)
})
@Getter
@Accessors(fluent = true, chain = true)
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class AbstractA {

    @JsonProperty
    protected final String superProperty;
}
```

And the subclass:

```
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Accessors(fluent = true, chain = true)
@SuperBuilder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = SubA.SubABuilder.class) // class not found?
@JsonTypeName("SubA")
public class SubA extends AbstractA {

    @JsonProperty
    private final String fieldA;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A working solution in Eclipse, note that the Lombok IntelliJ integration is not supporting all features, therefore the code compiles fine in Eclipse and with javac but IntelliJ thinks it's broken but executes the code without an issue.

```
public static ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {

        @Override
        public JsonPOJOBuilder.Value findPOJOBuilderConfig(final AnnotatedClass ac) {
            if (ac.hasAnnotation(JsonPOJOBuilder.class)) {
                return super.findPOJOBuilderConfig(ac);
            }
            return new JsonPOJOBuilder.Value("build", "");
        }
    });

    return mapper;
}

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = createObjectMapper();

    final String serializedForm = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(SubA.builder().build());
    System.out.println(serializedForm);
    final SubA anA = objectMapper.readValue(serializedForm, SubA.class);
    System.out.println(anA);
}


@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Accessors(fluent = true, chain = true)
@SuperBuilder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = SubA.SubABuilderImpl.class)
@JsonTypeName("SubA")
public static class SubA extends AbstractA {

    @JsonProperty
    private final String fieldA;
}


@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubA.class)
})
@Getter
@Accessors(fluent = true, chain = true)
@SuperBuilder
public static abstract class AbstractA {

    @JsonProperty
    protected final String superProperty;
}
```

Comment: I think you are right, the IntelliJ plugin has problems generating the code with the annotation.
Interesting solution with the JsonPOJOBuilder.
All in all, I'll use a different approach than SuperBuilder now. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 24):

*Updated 2018-11-10: Lombok 1.18.4 released*

*Updated 2020-10-18: Lombok 1.18.16 released*

**Lombok 1.18.16** contains the new [`@Jacksonized` annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized). With it, you can simply write:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubA.class),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AnotherSub.class)
})
@Jacksonized
@SuperBuilder
// more annotations...
public abstract class AbstractA {

    @JsonProperty
    protected final String superProperty;
}

@Jacksonized
@SuperBuilder
@JsonTypeName("SubA")
// more annotations...
public class SubA extends AbstractA {

    @JsonProperty
    private final String fieldA;
}
```

This will automatically insert all necessary Jackson annotations and do some adjustments to the generated builder. No need to customized anymore.

For earlier **Lombok versions between 1.18.4 and 1.18.12**, this is the way to go:

For Lombok's `@Builder` and `@SuperBuilder` to work with Jackson, you have to add the builder class header manually and place a `@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix="")` on it. Lombok will then generate only the remainder of the builder class. This is necessary because Jackson's default is that the builder's setter methods have "with" as prefix, but Lombok's builders don't have any prefix (and Lombok is not and will probably never be configurable in this regard).

When `@SuperBuilder` was introduced in Lombok 1.18.2, it was not customizable (i.e., you could not manually add the builder class header). As a result, using `@SuperBuilder` with Jackson was not easily possible.

This changed with Lombok 1.18.4 (see [this pull request](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/pull/1871)): `@SuperBuilder` is now (at least partially) customizable, and this allows us to add the annotation. Beware that the code generated by `@SuperBuilder` is quite complex and heavily loaded with generics. To avoid accidentally messing up the code, you should have a look at the *delombok* output and copy/paste the class header from there. Here, you need add the builder implementation class header and put the annotation on it:

```
@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix="")
static final class SubABuilderImpl extends SubABuilder<SubA, SubABuilderImpl> {
}
```

Note that you have to broaden the visibility of `SubABuilderImpl` to at least package-private.

The `@JsonDeserialize` annotation must also refer to the builder implementation class, not the abstract builder:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = SubA.SubABuilderImpl.class)
```

Comment: So as a result, you say that using the @SuperBuilder is currently not possible?

Comment: It is usable, only that it cannot be used for deserialization with Jackson.

Comment: Lombok 1.18.4 has been released, allowing customized `@SuperBuilder`s now. I update my answer with a working solution.

Comment: This solution worked for me. The only minor irritation is that Eclipse reports a handful of errors with this syntax:

`Multiple markers at this line`
 `- implements com.company.SubA.SubABuilder<com.company.SubA,com.company.SubA.SubABuilderImpl>.self`
 `- The method $fillValuesFrom(C) is undefined for the type SubA.SubABuilder<C,B>`
 `- The method $fillValuesFrom(C) of type SubA.SubABuilderBuilder<C,B> must override or implement a supertype method`
 `- implements com.company.SubA.SubABuilder<C,B>.self`

If anyone has any suggestions for resolving these, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: First make sure the Lombok version installed in eclipse matches the version in maven/grade. The message you are seeing looks like you don't have `toBuilder=true` on all classes in the hierarchy.

Comment: Yep, that was exactly it. I didn't have `toBuilder=true` on the base class.