# Why is JsonDeserialize not able to contruct classes using Lombok SuperBuilder

Tags: java, lombok, jackson-databind

I am trying to create an object model that represents a hierarchy of nested device locations.  For example a 'deck' contains a 'slide tray' which contains one or more 'slides'.  I want to be able to read in a json file that contains the hierarchy/configuration of the system. I want to use Lombok builders in my classes so I can safely generate the json files in code when I need to. The more common use case is to read in the json file to create the pojo's on application startup.  Generating the json files with the builder works great.  However, I have not been to de-serialize the file back into pojo's.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `my.org.Deck$DeckBuilder` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"type":"Deck","locNumber":1,
```

The top level super-class is this:

```
package my.org;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Singular;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.List;


@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Deck.class, name = "Deck"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SlideTray.class, name = "SlideTray"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Slide.class, name = "Slide"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = NullLoc.class, name = "null"),
})
@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@Accessors(fluent = true, chain = true)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = BaseLocationType.BaseLocationTypeBuilder.class)
public class BaseLocationType<T extends BaseLocationType> {

    @JsonProperty("locNumber")
    private int locNumber;

    @JsonProperty("posRelativeToParent")
    private Point2D.Double positionRelativeToParent;

    @Singular
    @JsonProperty("childLocs")
    private List<T> childLocs;

}
```

The Deck sub-class:

```
package my.org;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Accessors(fluent = true, chain = true)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Deck.DeckBuilder.class)
public class Deck extends BaseLocationType<SlideTray> {

    private String deckField1;

    private String deckField2;


}
```

The SlideTray sub-class:

```
package my.org;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Accessors(fluent = true, chain = true)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = SlideTray.SlideTrayBuilder.class)
public class SlideTray extends BaseLocationType<Slide> {

    private String slideTrayField1;

}
```

The Slide sub-class:

```
package my.org;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Accessors(fluent = true, chain = true)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Slide.SlideBuilder.class)
public class Slide extends BaseLocationType<NullLoc> {

    private String slideField1;

}
```

NullLoc:

```
package my.org;

import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@SuperBuilder
public class NullLoc extends BaseLocationType<NullLoc> {

    // no fields or builder, etc
}
```

Test Code - fails with the above exception on mapper.readValue():

```
// create 1 deck with 1 slideTray that has 2 slides
Deck.DeckBuilder<?, ?> deckBuilder = Deck.builder()
        .locNumber(1)
        .positionRelativeToParent(new Point2D.Double(1.0, 1.0))
        .deckField1("deck f1 data")
        .deckField2("deck f2 data")
        .childLoc(SlideTray.builder()
                .locNumber(2)
                .positionRelativeToParent(new Point2D.Double(2.0, 2.0))
                .slideTrayField1("slide tray f1 data")
                .childLoc(Slide.builder()
                        .locNumber(3)
                        .positionRelativeToParent(new Point2D.Double(3.0, 3.0))
                        .slideField1("child1-slide f1 data")
                        .build())
                .childLoc(Slide.builder()
                        .locNumber(4)
                        .positionRelativeToParent(new Point2D.Double(4.0, 4.0))
                        .slideField1("child2-slide f1 data")
                        .build()).build());

Deck deckPojo = deckBuilder.build();

// serialize the pojo's
String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(deckPojo);

// de-serialize the json back into the pojo's
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Deck deckPojoDeserialized = mapper.readValue(json, Deck.class);
```

The json that is generated:

```
{
  "type": "Deck",
  "locNumber": 1,
  "posRelativeToParent": {
    "x": 1.0,
    "y": 1.0
  },
  "childLocs": [
    {
      "type": "SlideTray",
      "locNumber": 2,
      "posRelativeToParent": {
        "x": 2.0,
        "y": 2.0
      },
      "childLocs": [
        {
          "type": "Slide",
          "locNumber": 3,
          "posRelativeToParent": {
            "x": 3.0,
            "y": 3.0
          },
          "childLocs": []
        },
        {
          "type": "Slide",
          "locNumber": 4,
          "posRelativeToParent": {
            "x": 4.0,
            "y": 4.0
          },
          "childLocs": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

note: I'm not seeing a option here in stackoverflow to upload the demo-project zip file... but can figure out a way to share that if needed. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the root problem is related to the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation `builder` values defined across the three primary sub-classes, because they appear to be `abstract` `class` references. Which would also explain the error message you're receiving.

From the `Lombok` `@SuperBuilder` documentation <sup>[ref](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder)</sup>:

> To ensure type-safety, @SuperBuilder generates two inner builder classes for each annotated class, one abstract and one concrete class named FoobarBuilder and FoobarBuilderImpl (where Foobar is the name of the annotated class).

I believe updating the following `@JsonDeserialize` annotation `builder` values will help resolve the issue:

In the `Deck` sub-class:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Deck.DeckBuilderImpl.class)
```

In the `SlideTray` sub-class:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = SlideTray.SlideTrayBuilderImpl.class)
```

In the `Slide` sub-class:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Slide.SlideBuilderImpl.class)
```

---

### Additional note with respect to `BuilderImpl` manual updates:

The `@SuperBuilder` documentation[<sup>ref</sup>](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder) includes the following supporting information relative to this topic:

> Customizing the code generated by @SuperBuilder is limited to adding new methods or annotations to the builder classes, and providing custom implementations of the 'set', builder(), and build() methods. You have to make sure that the builder class declaration headers match those that would have been generated by lombok. Due to the heavy generics usage, we strongly advice to copy the builder class definition header from the uncustomized delomboked code.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for your answer.  Using the impl classes, the code fails to compile since they are are generated as a private static classes.  So I de-lomboked them and made the impl classes package private and it worked.  

note: I had to remove @JsonProperty("locNumber") on the base class so there appears to be some issue with integrating jackson.

Comment: Having to de-lombok cannot be the intended use here, right?   I'm not seeing any way to get around this though.

Comment: My bad - I meant to warn you about the secondary visibility issue. It crossed my mind, but then I was focused on going through your code, and it completely slipped my mind. But you already put in the fix I forgot to include in my answer, so that's resolved.

Comment: With respect to the Jackson related issue you ran into, the root cause is likely that the Jackson default handling expects the builder mutator methods to include a "with" prefix, while Lombok uses the base field name. If that's the issue, adding the annotation:  `@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix="")` to the concrete builder impl class (the same class you delomboked, just to be clear) should resolve the problem.

Comment: And following up with respect to your delombok misgivings, I hear you loud and clear. But this (ugly) work-around is the only solution that I've found, so I score it in the lesser-evil category and bear it. And I haven't checked in some time, but I remember a Lombok dev team discussion that was hopeful about a proposed solution, but that may have ultimately been discarded as not viable.

Comment: Thanks Sean... extremely helpful!

Comment: Another thought... There must be a complex reason for the lombok folks to not simply change the byte code generator to make the impl package private.  Which makes me wonder if de-lomboking and changing the private-ness of the impl class has a fundamental/security issue that the lombok folks want to avoid.

Comment: When `@SuperBuilder` was introduced (in Lombok 1.18.2), no customization was allowed, so manually adding the `BuilderImpl` class header wasn't permitted. But that essentially rendered  `@SuperBuilder` incompatible with Jackson. To resolve that issue, limited customization of `@SuperBuilder` was added (in Lombok 1.18.4) to allow: manual addition of the `BuilderImpl` class header, manual addition of the `@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix="")` annotation, and broadening the visibility of the `BuilderImpl` to at least `package-private`.

Comment: I added a note to the answer that includes content from the `@SuperBuilder` documentation related to the delombok `BuilderImpl` manual changes. I think it (partially) addresses your concern with respect to broadening the visibility (from `private`) and may be of interest.

Comment: There is `@Jacksonized` lombok annotation, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52734470/2455388) answer