# How to deserialize a class with lombook @SuperBuilder by jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

I have a project with spring boot, jackson (2.9.7),lombook (1.18.4).
The problem is - deserialize a class, which i can't refactor (because it comes from external lib and using another external libs). I want to deserialize my http request with json body to UpperClass. What can i do, to resolve this problem? This my code:
Upper class:

```
@Value
@NonFinal
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=true)
public class UpperClass extends BaseClass {
 String message;
}
```

Base class:

```
@Value
@NonFinal
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BaseClass {
 protected String status;
}
```

My endpoint:

```
@POST
@PATH("/test")
public void getTest(@RequestBody UpperClass upperClass) {
 log.info(upperClass.toString());
}
```

Error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of UpperClass: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

Comment: I suggest you should upgrade the `Lombok` version

Comment: There is `@Jacksonized` lombok annotation, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52734470/2455388) answer

Answer (score 1):

The result of my investigations:

1. Create the custom deserializer:

   ```
    public class UpperClassDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<UpperClass> {
     public UpperClassDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);}

     public UpperClassDeserializer() {
        this(null);}

    @Override
    public UpperClass deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOExcetion {
        JsonNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);
        String message = node.get("message").toString();
        String status = node.get("status").toString();
        return UpperClass.builder().message(message).status(status).build();
    }
   ```

   }

2.Create the custom jaxrs json provider and use objectMapper from there:

```
public class MyCustomJaxrsJsonProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
@Override
public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
 SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
 module.addDeserializer(UpperClass.class, new UpperClassDeserializer());
 return new CustomJsonMapperFactory().getObject().registerModule(new Jdk8Module()).registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()).registerModule(module);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. put @Setter and @Setter on top of the UpperClass and BaseClass
2. put @AllArgsConstructor on top of the UpperClass

Comment: So, make your model. fill UpperClass with that